# Save Image with filter to Photo Library in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, ios10, core-image, cifilter

I'm using Core Image in Swift for editing photos and I have a problem when I save the photo. After applying a filter to the photo, it can not be saved. But without the filter, it can be saved. Any ideas how?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pickedImaged: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func camerabuttonaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


@IBAction func photolibraryaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


@IBAction func saveaction(_ sender: UIButton) {
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImaged.image!, nil, nil, nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {   
    pickedImaged.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);     
}


@IBAction func addfilter(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let image = pickedImaged.image, cgimg = image?.cgImage
    let coreImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)      
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
    filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)     
    let output = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage
    let filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: output!)
    pickedImaged.image = filteredImage       
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

My code works for both iOS 9 & iOS 10:

(1) I use the iOS share extension, which always gives you the ability to copy to clipboard and "save" functions, along with Message, Mail, etc. Code is below.

(2) Without seeing the photo editing code, I may be stating the obvious. But - make sure you (a) are supplying the CI Filter output to things and (b) are properly supplying the filter the needed parameters.

I have certain types of "shares" commented out, but here's what I do:

```
let context = CIContext()
let final = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage, from: filter.outputImage.extent)
let shareImage = UIImage(cgImage: final!)
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareImage], applicationActivities: [])
vc.excludedActivityTypes =  [
    //UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
    //UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
    UIActivityType.postToWeibo,
    //UIActivityTypeMessage,
    //UIActivityTypeMail,
    UIActivityType.print,
    //UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
    UIActivityType.assignToContact,
    //UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
    UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
    //UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
    UIActivityType.postToVimeo,
    UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo
]
present(vc,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
vc.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activity, success, items, error) in
}
```

Comment: Thx @dfd I have try many way but not work, until change ciImage to ciImage like you said. THANK YOU!